# Bads results with gpu program

Tags: opencl, gpu

I haven't got good results with an iterative equation solving.
I am using a 2D array with "size_y" rows with "size_x" elements for each row.

The problem is that the code only does one iteration because the error cumulative is equal to zero. This cumulative error is computed in the kernel code for each cell of the array.

Here are 2 parts of sources files of this solving :

kernel code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define min(a,b) a <= b ? a : b

// kernel code

const char *source =
"__kernel void line_compute(__global double diagx, __global double diagy,\
__global double weightx, __global double weighty, __global int size_x,\
__global double* tab_process, __global double* tab_new, __global double* r) {\
  const unsigned int iy = get_global_id(0);\
  const unsigned int ix = get_global_id(1);\
  /* do computation */\
  tab_process[iy*size_x+ix] = weighty *( tab_new[(iy-1)*size_x+ix] +\
  tab_new[(i+1)*size_x+ix] + tab_new[iy*size_x+ix]*diagy)+\
  weightx *( tab_new[iy*size_x+(ix-1)] + tab_new[iy*size_x+(ix+1)] + tab_new[iy*size_x+ix]*diagx) ; \
  r[iy*size_x+ix] = 0;\
  rk = tab_new[iy*size_x+ix] - tab_process[iy*size_x+ix];\
  r[iy*size_x+ix] =r[iy*size_x+ix]+ rk * rk;\
  tab_new[iy*size_x+ix] = tab_process[iy*size_x+ix]\
}";
```

At the execution, the cumulative error that I print with :

```c
result = 0.0;
        for(i=1;i<=size_x*size_y;i++)
             { result = result + r[i];
           printf("r[%d]=%20.18f\n",i,r[i]);
         }

        printf("result=%f\n",result);
        *error=result;
```

is equal to zero. That's why the code only does one iteration.

I don't understand where the probem is.
If anyone could see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Please, when posting questions to Stack Overflow, isolate only the relevant sections of the code (and format it properly). This one is too much for anyone to look at.

Besides prematurely updating the `tab_new` at the end of the kernel (you should do it only once after all threads have finished since neighbouring values are dependent), you have a syntax error in the kernel source:

```c
tab_process[iy*size_x+ix] = weighty *( tab_new[(iy-1)*size_x+ix] +\
>>>  tab_new[(i+1)*size_x+ix] <<< + tab_new[iy*size_x+ix]*diagy)+\
weightx *( tab_new[iy*size_x+(ix-1)] + tab_new[iy*size_x+(ix+1)] + tab_new[iy*size_x+ix]*diagx) ; \
```

You have mistakenly written `i` instead of `iy`. So the program would most likely not compile in `clCreateProgramWithSource`. Because you don't check the return code in `ret`, you miss that fact and then the following `clCreateKernel` and `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` are also failing. With no kernel being executed the value of `r_mem_obj` remains the same as its initial value - all zeros, because it is a copy of `r` which, as a freshly allocated heap memory, is also all zeros (newly commited after a read fault pages on Linux are CoW mapped to a special all-zeros page in the kernel). Summing up all zeros gives zero.